# Build object in JavaScript from PHP form input name

Tags: javascript, forms, object

There are a couple of similar questions but none covers the case when a string looks like `some-name[][some-key]`. I have tried `JSON.parse('some-name[][some-key]');` but it doesn't parse it.

Is there a way to convert such string to a JavaScript object that will look like `{ 'some-name': { 0: { 'some-key': '' } } }`?

This is a name of a form field. It's normally parsed by PHP but I'd like to parse it with JavaScript the same way. I basically have `<input name="some-name[][some-key]">` and I'd like to convert that to `var something = { 'some-name': { 0: { 'some-key': VALUE-OF-THIS-FIELD } } }`.

Comment: I have a feeling this is an example of the XY problem. In any case, how variable are the strings? Are they always this format? Will there ever be something in the first bracket set? Examples of possible strings and their result would be useful

Comment: @SmokeyPHP There may be something in the first brackets. I have added an empty brackets to indicate that PHP automatically fills it with proper keys and I'd like to maintain this functionality in JavaScript.

Comment: Is this a per-field conversion, or will you want all the fields with the same `some-name` to be compiled into one object? i.e. `{'some-name': {0:...,1:...,2:...}`

Comment: Any of those are fine with me. I can merge that into one object later on. When a form is submitted with PHP I would have this available in `$_REQUEST['some-name']` - ideally this should parse it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSON.parse('{ "some-name": [ {   "some-key": "" }   ] }');
```

Comment: I have `<input name="some-name[][some-key]">` and I'd like to convert that to `var something = { 'some-name': { 0: { 'some-key': VALUE-OF-THIS-FIELD } } }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you're doing this, but assuming they are all that format (`name[][key]`) and you need to do them one by one - this works for me:

```
var fieldObj = {};
function parseFieldName(nameStr)
{
    var parts = nameStr.match(/[^[\]]+/g);
    var name = parts[0];
    var key = typeof parts[parts.length-1] != 'undefined' ? parts[parts.length-1] : false;
    if(key===false) return false;
    else
    {
        if(!fieldObj.hasOwnProperty(name)) fieldObj[name] = [];
        var o = {};
        o[key] = 'val';
        fieldObj[name].push(o);
    }
}
parseFieldName('some-name[][some-key]');
parseFieldName('some-name[][some-key2]');
parseFieldName('some-name2[][some-key]');
console.log(fieldObj); //Firebug shows: Object { some-name=[2], some-name2=[1]}  -- stringified: {"some-name":[{"some-key":"val"},{"some-key2":"val"}],"some-name2":[{"some-key":"val"}]}
```

`o[key] = 'val';` could of course be changed to `o[key] = $("[name="+nameStr+"]").val()` or however you want to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var input = …,
    something = {};

var names = input.name.match(/^[^[\]]*|[^[\]]*(?=\])/g);
for (var o=something, i=0; i<names.length-1; i++) {
    if (names[i])
        o = o[names[i]] || (o[names[i]] = names[i+1] ? {} : []);
    else
        o.push(o = names[i+1] ? {} : []);
}
if (names[i])
    o[names[i]] = input.value;
else
    o.push(input.value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: according to your updated example, you can make something like this (view below). This will work - but only with the current example.

```
var convertor = function(element) {
    var elementName = element.getAttribute('name');

    var inpIndex = elementName.substring(0, elementName.indexOf('[')),
        keyIndex = elementName.substring(elementName.lastIndexOf('[') + 1, elementName.lastIndexOf(']'));

    var strToObj = "var x = {'" + inpIndex + "': [{'" + keyIndex + "': '" + element.value + "'}]}";
    eval(strToObj);
    return x;
};
var myObject = convertor(document.getElementById('yourInputID'));
```

**Example here:** http://paulrad.com/stackoverflow/string-to-array-object.html
*(result is visible in the console.log)*

---

**old response**

Use `eval`.. but your string must have a **valid javascript syntax**

So:

```
var str = "arr[][123] = 'toto'";
eval(str);
console.log(arr);
```

Will return a syntax error

Valid syntax will be:

```
var str = "var arr = []; arr[123] = 'toto'";
var x = eval(str);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that will work but I hoped I can avoid `indexOf`, regexp and similar methods of doing this :) I hoped that I can get something like PHP's `$_REQUEST['some-name']` to use in JavaScript, without reloading the page and without submitting the form. It looks like something like that is not available though...